# Bryant-Salamon $G_2$ manifold on the spinor bundle over $S^3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry, holonomy, spinor

I am trying to understand the spaces constructed in R. L. Bryant and S. M. Salamon, *On the construction of some complete metrics with exceptional holonomy*.
My first problem is, essentially, about their definition of spinor bundle.

1. Let's consider the first case: $\mathbb{S}$ spinor bundle over $S^3$.

By my understanding of spin geometry, $\mathbb{S}:=\mathcal{F}\times_\rho \mathbb{H}$, where $\rho:\text{Sp(1)}\to\text{GL}(\mathbb{H})$ is just given by left multiplication and $\mathcal{F}$ is the double cover of the frame bundle. However, in their definition it looks like $\mathbb{S}=\tilde{\mathcal{F}}\times_\tilde{\rho} \mathbb{H}$, where $\tilde{\rho}:\text{Sp(1)}\to\text{GL}(\mathbb{H})$ is given by right multiplication of the inverse and $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ should be the coframe bundle. I would guess that these two should be the same because the two actions are dual. However, I am not sure how to prove that.

2. My second problem is that in local coordinates, I do not get the same vertical forms ($\alpha$) as in the paper. Let me briefly explain what I did.

Realizing the Clifford Algebra $Cl(3)$ as in Harvey, *Spinors and Calibrations* p. 300, i.e.,
we use as generators $\mathbb{R}^3\cong\Im \mathbb{H}\to \text{Diag}(M_2(\mathbb{H}))$ such that $q\mapsto \text{Diag}(q,-q)$.

More or less like in Karigiannis and Lotay, *Bryant-Salamon* $G_2$ *manifolds and coassociative fibrations*, given a local orthonormal frame $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ of $S^3$, I computed the connection matrix $\omega_{ij}$ and I parametrize the fibres of $\mathbb{S}$ by $a_01+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k$ ($\{1,i,j,k\}$ basis of the fiber). Using the famous formula for the connection on the spinor bundle:

$$
\nabla\sigma_\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i<j}\omega_{ij} e_i\cdot e_j\cdot\sigma_\alpha,
$$

we compute the connection matrix for $\mathbb{S}$. As an example, $\nabla i$ is:
$$
2\nabla i=-\omega_{12} i\cdot j\cdot i - \omega_{13} i\cdot k\cdot i-\omega_{23}j\cdot k\cdot i=-\omega_{12} j - \omega_{13} k+\omega_{23}1.
$$
Two times the full connection matrix of the spinor bundle is:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \omega_{23} &-\omega_{13} &\omega_{12}\\
-\omega_{23} &0 &\omega_{12} &\omega_{13} \\
\omega_{13} &-\omega_{12} & 0 &\omega_{23} \\
-\omega_{12} & -\omega_{13} &-\omega_{23} &0
\end{bmatrix}

Since in Bryant-Salamon they work with $\Im \mathbb{H}$ instead that with $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, we can identify $\omega_{12}=-2\rho_3$, $\omega_{23}=-2\rho_1$ and $\omega_{13}=2\rho_2$ ($\rho$ should be as in Karigiannis Lotay and $\phi$ in the notation of Bryant-Salamon should just be -$\rho$ because of frame/coframe connection differs by a change of sign), and we rewrite the connection form as:
$$\tilde{\omega}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\rho_{1} &-\rho_{2} &-\rho_{3}\\
\rho_{1} &0 &-\rho_{3} &\rho_{2} \\
\rho_{2} & \rho_{3} & 0 &-\rho_{1} \\
\rho_{3} & -\rho_{2} &\rho_{1} &0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Finally,
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\alpha}_0&=da_0+\sum_i\tilde{\omega}_{0i} a_i=da_0-a_1\rho_{1}-a_2\rho_{2}-a_3\rho_{3};\\
\tilde{\alpha}_1&=da_1+a_0\rho_{1}-a_2\rho_3+a_3\rho_2;\\
...
\end{align*}
We already see that $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ does not coincide with the one in Bryant-Salamon, which should have the form:
\begin{align*}
\alpha_0&=da_0+a_1\phi_{1}+a_2\phi_{2}+a_3\phi_{3};\\
\alpha_1&=da_1-a_0\phi_{1}-a_2\phi_3+a_3\phi_2;\\
...
\end{align*}

So, if it is true that $\phi=-\rho$, $\alpha_0$ and $\tilde{\alpha}_0$ coincide, but $\tilde{\alpha}_1\neq
{\alpha}_1$. Analogous problems arise in $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$.

I would be very grateful you could help me understand where I made a mistake/ how could I fix my problems.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: I forgot the definition of $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$, which should be the coframe bundle. I have also added it in the text.

Comment: The answer to your first question is a simple isomorphism:  The conjugation map on $\mathbb{H}$ converts right quaternion multiplication into left multiplication:  $$\overline{xq} = \bar q\,\bar x,$$ so if you don't like the right action $$(\tilde u,\  x)\cdot q = (\tilde u{\cdot}q,\ xq)$$ that we use in our paper, replace it with the right action  $$(\tilde u,\ x)\cdot q = (\tilde u{\cdot}q,\ \bar q\,x).$$  This change also changes some more signs further on, and this might also answer your second question.

Comment: Thank you very much, Prof. Bryant. Your comment almost solved question 2. Indeed, if $\phi$ were equal to $\rho$, I would precisely get the right forms. However, $\phi$, being the connection of the coframe bundle, should be$-\rho$. Did you counter that problem with the minus in $da-a\phi$?

I have just realized that I didn't say that $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ was (should be) the coframe bundle. In light of this difference, how do we get the equivalence of the two definitions of the spinor bundle? Is it related to an isomorphism between frame and coframe?